# UIPageViewController - each pages display a different Webview

Tags: xcode, uiwebview, uipageviewcontroller

I would like to know how can I display on each pages of an `UIPageViewController` a different UIWebView's URL, let say that the first pdf is one.pdf, the second one two.pdf etc...

I'm using the UIPageViewController in Xcode 4.2

Comment: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_iOS_5_iPhone_UIPageViewController_Application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to create a custom viewController subclass.

```
@interface WebViewController : UIViewController

- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)url frame:(CGRect)frame;

@property (retain) NSURL *url;

@end
```

In this example I have called the class WebViewController and given it a custom initialiser method. (Also given it a property to hold the url).

first in you implementation you should synthesise that property

```
@implementation WebViewController

@synthesize url = _url;
```

In also in the implementation you should do something like this to create you init method:

```
- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)url frame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.url = url;
    }
    return self;
}
```

remembering you will also need (if not using ARC):

```
- (void)dealloc {
    self.url = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

then you will also need to have a:

```
- (void)loadView {
    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:self.url];
    [webView loadRequest:request];
    [webView release]; // remove this line if using ARC

    // EDIT :You could add buttons that will be on all the controllers (pages) here
    UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTap) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:button1];
}
```

Also remember you will then need to implement the method

```
- (void)buttonTap {
    // Do something when the button is tapped
}

// END EDIT
```

In your main controller that has the UIPageViewController you will need to do something along the lines of:

```
NSMutableArray *controllerArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < urlArray.count; i++) {
    WebViewController *webViewController = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithURL:[urlArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    [controllerArray addObject:webViewController];
// EDIT: If you wanted different button on each controller (page) then you could add then here
UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTap) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[webViewController.view addSubview:button1];
// In this case you will need to put the "buttonTap" method on this controller NOT on the webViewController. So that you can handle the buttons differently from each controller.
// END EDIT

[webViewController release]; // remove this if using ARC
}
pageViewController.viewControllers = controllerArray;
```

So we basically, just created an instance of your WebViewController class for each page that you want to display, then added them all as the array of viewControllers for your UIPageViewController to page between.

Assuming that urlArray is a valid NSArray containing NSURL objects for all of the pages that you want to load, and that you have create a UIPageViewController and added it to your view hierarchy then this should do the trick.

Hope this helps, if you need any clarification or further help, let me know :)

Comment: could you add buttons on those views if you wanted to?

Comment: Absolutely, just add them to the controller. Either in the controller itself, if you want them to be the same on each. Or when you create the controllers. Just about to update the answer to include this.

Comment: Updated, had showed adding buttons in two places. You probably don't need to do it in both. But you may depending on what you need the buttons for?